# js parallax effect not working in two background section on page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, parallax.js

I have a parallax function applied in two backgrounds sections on the homepage.(1 and 4 sections)
The parallex works correct on the first section but on section 4, the image disappears.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
 parallax();
})
function parallax() {
 var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
 $('.parallax').css('background-position','center '+(wScroll*0.75)+'px')
}
```

```html
              <!doctype html>
              <html lang="en">
                <head>
                  <title>Hello, world!</title>
                  <!-- Required meta tags -->
                  <meta charset="utf-8">
                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

                  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
               

                   <style>
                
                     section.masthead2{
                        background-image:url("https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/b807c2282ab0a491bd5c5c1051c6d312_rP0kQjJ.jpg");
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-position: center ;
                        -webkit-background-size: cover;
                        -moz-background-size: cover;
                        -o-background-size: cover;
                        background-size: cover;
                        height:80vh;
                        
                      }
                      section.masthead3{
                        background-color:orange;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-attachment: scroll;
                        background-position: center center;
                        -webkit-background-size: cover;
                        -moz-background-size: cover;
                        -o-background-size: cover;
                        background-size: cover;
                        height:80vh;
                        position:relative;
                      }
                      section.masthead4{
                        background-image:url("https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/b807c2282ab0a491bd5c5c1051c6d312_rP0kQjJ.jpg");
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-attachment: scroll;
                        background-position: center center;
                        -webkit-background-size: cover;
                        -moz-background-size: cover;
                        -o-background-size: cover;
                        background-size: cover;
                        height:80vh;
                        position:relative;
                      }
                      section.masthead5{
                        background-color:green;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-attachment: scroll;
                        background-position: center center;
                        -webkit-background-size: cover;
                        -moz-background-size: cover;
                        -o-background-size: cover;
                        background-size: cover;
                        height:80vh;
                        position:relative;
                      }
                      
                   </style>
                      
                </head>
                <body>
                <section class="container-fluid masthead2 parallax d-flex  align-items-center justify-content-center">
                </section>

                <section class="container-fluid masthead3 d-flex  align-items-center justify-content-center">  
                </section>

                <section class="container-fluid masthead4 parallax d-flex  align-items-center justify-content-center">  
                </section>

                <section class="container-fluid masthead5 d-flex  align-items-center justify-content-center">  
                </section>
                

                    
                
                  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
                  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
                  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                  <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
                  <script src="js/parallax.js"></script>
                </body>
              </html>
```

Testing in Inspect Element I noticed that the background-position element for section4 has some pixel values.

[image]

If I then set the pixels to 0px, the image shows:

[image]

I assume this is happening on how the JS function is working.
I'm new into JS and the web world, so apologies for any misunderstanding!
Do I need to create a separate JS function for the other section?

Comment: If you have a look what scrollTop() does you understand why it is not working for the section 4. https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: which parallax library are you using? I'm a maintainer or [parallax.js](http://pixelcog.com/parallax.js/) and came across this, but the code doesn't seem familiar

Comment: The parallax code was extracted from a Youtube explanation. It works perfectly with the first image of the site but the other one does not, since the image indeed is displaced and therefore that div section shows blank, but not sure how to correct it.